# DataTable control: Zebra striping not displaying on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, primefaces, zebra-striping

We're having some slight problems with our Zebra striping implementation. While it displays alternating colors in FF 3.6 and Chrome 10, it does not work in IE 8. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
 <p:dataTable id="newMsgTable" 
 var="newAggr" 
 value="#{messageAggregatorBean.newAggregator}"
 rowStyleClass="#{empty rowIx or rowIx
 mod 2 ne 0 ? 'even-row' : 'odd-row'}"
 rowIndexVar="rowIx">
```

Css:

```
 .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data .even-row td {
     background-color:#efffe6;
     border-right: solid 0px #4e6769; 
 }

 .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data .odd-row td { 
     background-color:#ffffff;
     border-right: solid 0px #4e6769; 
 }
```

Also posted at:
http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5713&p=34932#p34932

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in IE 8 for me:

dataTable

```
<p:dataTable var="entry" value="#{myBean.list}" rowIndexVar="rowIx"
    rowStyleClass="#{rowIx mod 2 ne 0 ? 'odd-row' : 'even-row'}">
```

included stylesheet

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="page.css" />
```

stylesheet

```
.even-row {
    background: #fcefa1;
}

.odd-row {
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```